# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded when decrypt file

Tags: java, encryption, des

I am writing a small secure storage server simulation, in order to get familira with Cryptography techniques and algorithms. I stucked on decryption of file content. Project is a little bit large to put it all here, so I will put excepts ( methods which I use and where problem occurs) from code.
Problem is, when I try to decrypt file,BadPaddingException happens.
Excepts of Crypto class, where main crypto logic is implemented

```
public class Crypto {

private Cipher asymmCipher;
//one cipher for asymmetric and one for symmetric
private Cipher symmCipher;

public IvParameterSpec iv;
SecureRandom sr;
KeyGenerator kg;

   public Crypto() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
      this.asymmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      this.symmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
   }
 /*
        Method for symmetric encription of file
 */
  public byte[] SymmetricFileEncryption(byte[] file, SecretKey key)
          throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
          BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

      this.symmCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

      return this.symmCipher.doFinal(file);
  }

 /*
        Method for symmetric decription of file
 */
  public byte[] SymmetricFileDecription(byte[] file, SecretKey key)
          throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
          BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
      this.symmCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
      return this.symmCipher.doFinal(file);
  }
    /*
        Method for write encrypted file
 */
public void writeToFile(File output, byte[] data, SecretKey key)
        throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, 
        IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
    byte[] encContent = SymmetricFileEncryption(data, key);
    fos.write(encContent);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
   public byte[] readFromFile(File input, SecretKey key)
        throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, 
        IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int) input.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
    fis.read(fileContent);
    fis.close();

    return SymmetricFileDecription(fileContent, key);
}

}
```

When I try to use symmetric file enc and dec one after other like :

```
                    String test = "Test symmetric file enc / dec";
                    byte[] tesT = aCrypto.SymmetricFileEncryption(test.getBytes(), sessionKey);
                    System.out.println("ENC FROM SERVER " + new String(tesT));
                    String test2 = new String(aCrypto.SymmetricFileDecription(tesT, sessionKey));
                    System.out.println("DEC FROM SERVER: " + test2);
```

it works well.

Except from Server for new File creation and for edit file(where I need reading and decrypting)

```
               if ("new".equals(option)) {
                    String fileName = aCrypto.DecryptStringSymmetric((String) ois.readObject(), sessionKey);
                    System.out.println("FILE NAME SERVER POSLAN IS UPANEL CONTROLLERA : " + fileName);
                    // String cFileName = aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric(fileName, sessionKey);
                    String formatedEncFileName = aCrypto.encodeWithSHA256(fileName).replaceAll("\\/", "");
                    File f = new File("src/server/users/" + userName + "/" + formatedEncFileName);

                    if (!f.exists()) {
                        f.createNewFile();
                        System.out.println("FILE CREATED!");
                        fileNamesMap.put(formatedEncFileName, fileName);
                        serialize(fileNamesMap);
                        System.out.println("MAP VALUE FOR " + fileNamesMap.get(formatedEncFileName));
                    }
                    byte[] file = aCrypto.SymmetricFileDecription(((byte[]) ois.readObject()), sessionKey);
                    System.out.println("FILE CONTENT :  " + new String(file));
                   // String encContent = aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric(new String(file), sessionKey);
                    aCrypto.writeToFile(f, file, sessionKey);
                    oos.writeObject(aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric(((f.exists()) ? "true" : "false"), sessionKey));
                    changeFileWatcher(userName);
                }
                    if (("edit").equals(option)) {
                    fileName = aCrypto.DecryptStringSymmetric((String) ois.readObject(), sessionKey);
                    byte[] content = aCrypto.readFromFile(new File(PATH + userName + "/" + (String)  getKeyFromValue(fileNamesMap, fileName.split("/")[4])), sessionKey); //Exception in readFromFile
                    String fileContent = aCrypto.DecryptStringSymmetric(new String(content), sessionKey);
                    oos.writeObject(aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric(fileContent, sessionKey));
                    System.out.println("NAME FROM SERVER IN EDIT : " + fileName);
                }
                if (("modify").equals(option)) {
                    String editedFileContent = aCrypto.DecryptStringSymmetric((String) ois.readObject(), sessionKey);
                    System.out.println("NAME FROM SERVER IN MODIFY: " + fileName);
                    String encrytedFileContent = aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric(editedFileContent, sessionKey);
                    File f = new File(PATH + userName + "/" + (String) getKeyFromValue(fileNamesMap, fileName.split("/")[4]));
                    aCrypto.writeToFile(f, encrytedFileContent.getBytes(), sessionKey);
                    oos.writeObject(aCrypto.EncryptStringSymmetric("true", sessionKey));
                }
```

Another example - I put print in writeToFile method and tested write and read :

```
    String test = "Test symmetric file enc / dec";
    File fileTest = new File("src/server/testFileEnc");
    if(!fileTest.exists()) {
        fileTest.createNewFile();
    }
    aCrypto.writeToFile(fileTest, test.getBytes(), sessionKey);
                    String decryptedFromFile = new String(aCrypto.readFromFile(fileTest , sessionKey));
    System.out.println("DECRYPTED DATA " + decryptedFromFile);
```

Output :

```
  ENCRYPTED DATA:  ×^đzŞĘňmř”›&şH«ťq
  DECRYPTED DATA : Test symmetric file enc / dec
```

Comment: BadPaddingException is usually just a symptom of the data being messed up somehow. To pinpoint whats wrong you need simplify thing. Start by verifying that your encrypt & decrypt works without all your file read / write and the various server thing etc ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested all methods, and it seems that they are working well :-/
I edited question with example that I added and that works well.
Problem occurs when I read a file after a while :-/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found problem. Problem is that I am a little bit dumb :)
I forgot that with every new client, new session key is generated, so even if I created encrypted file with specific user, after application restart, user is provided with new 3DES key, and with that new key I am trying to decrypt file encrypted with different 3DES key. 
I need to store session key on server, and to use same key for specific user

Comment: As you now realize a bad padding error generally just means that the decryption failed. AES was approved 16 years ago and 3DES is still being used? Hopefully with a 24-byte key.

Comment: Yes,  now I am aware of that.  In first,  I didn't think that it was bad key problem,  but I was obviously fault. I am using AES,  actually,  but in my despair,  I changed it to 3DES, just to see will it make any progression :)